# In-built laptop camera and mic don't work, are universal drivers available?

Tags: drivers, hardware, microphone, camera

I am using the Eve V 2-in-1 laptop from a small [enthusiasts manufacturer](https://euro.evedevices.com/pages/eve-v-2021-tech-specifications). The device came with windows installed and the in-built camera and microphone work with this OS. But more often I use the other partition on the device - Ubuntu 20.04.2. On it the in-built camera and mic don't work (but I can use external mics from headphones). From looking in the forums of the device I found that the device doesn't have drivers for the camera and mic for Linux. [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jFAkLui8WD7RtOzdtdfiHdmzEbp2U8dE/view?usp=sharing) you can see the output of my `lsusb` and `lsusb -v` commands. And [here](https://eve.community/t/enabling-the-vs-hardware-on-linux-wiki/12580/23) you can read a little bit more what people in the support forum have discussed. [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cvS-yRCYwwdL0sGJ6Bh0XxABivRyVBzP/view?usp=sharing) is the output of `sudo lshw -class multimedi`.

Is there a way to make the in-built camera and mic work on Ubuntu? Are there some kind of universal drivers? Tnx

Comment: To answer this question it will be important to know what those devices actually are. Can you update your question to include the output of `lsusb`?

Comment: @matigo thanks, I included the info you asked for, or at least I think so. Let me know if I should provide more :) I am not a Linux pro, so I don't know what would be useful